# No broadcast messages from macOS 10.12 Server

Tags: macos

I have several Mac OSX 10.12 servers running a vdi-environment.
Shutdown messages or wall messages will not be broadcasted to connected users. All Servers and Clients show "mesg y".

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Broadcast messages via "wall"-command do work, but only on tty sessions. Console session do not display the message.